# Page builder extend. Disable input if Link URL isn't filled in

Tags: page-builder

I'm extending a few page builder components. I need to disable the new inputs until the link url inside of Content has a value

[image: page builder banner form]

I can easily disable an input by using the value from another checkbox/select/input but the Link URL works different

This is what I have tried in the `pagebuilder_banner_form.xml`

```
<field name="test_input" sortOrder="96" formElement="checkbox">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="default" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                <item name="disabledValues" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="none" xsi:type="string"></item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <dataType>boolean</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Test Input</label>
            <dataScope>test_input</dataScope>
            <imports>
                <link name="setDisabled">ns = ${ $.ns }, index = link_url:value</link>
            </imports>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <checkbox>
                <settings>
                    <valueMap>
                        <map name="true" xsi:type="string">true</map>
                    </valueMap>
                    <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                </settings>
            </checkbox>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

I also tried `<link name="setDisabled">ns = ${ $.ns }, index = link_url:value.default</link>` which kinda works when I open the banner setting the first time but after I save it doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="disabledValues" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="none" xsi:type="string">default</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
```

and

```
            <imports>
                <link name="setDisabled">ns = ${ $.ns }, index = link_url:value</link>
            </imports>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I'm not working with Magento anymore so I can't verify whether this solution works or not.